# How to pass component into another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I use useEffect hook in which I want to get some Preview components and pass them into PreviewContainer. Preview component must contain "src", "alt" and "file size" parameters from reader.onload function. How can I do that correctly?

I've tried use previewElements with useState - doesn't work. Define previewElements variable also doesnt't work right.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '../Button/Button';
import PreviewContainer from '../PreviewContainer/PreviewContainer';
import Preview from '../Preview/Preview';

function Card({ accept }) {
  let [uploadDisabled, setUploadDisabled] = useState(true);
  let [multiple, setMultiple] = useState(true);
  let [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  let previewElements = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length) setUploadDisabled(false);

    previewElements = files.map((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const src = event.target.result;
        const alt = file.name;

        function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
          if (!+bytes) return '0 Bytes';

          const k = 1024;
          const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
          const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

          const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

          return `${parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm))} ${sizes[i]}`;
        }

        previewElements = [...previewElements, 123];
        console.log(previewElements);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }, [files]);

  function handleOpenClick() {
    const inputEl = document.getElementById('file');
    inputEl.click();
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!event.target.files) return;

    setFiles(Array.from(event.target.files));
  }

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <input
        type='file'
        id='file'
        multiple={multiple}
        onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
        accept={accept.join(',')}
      />
      <Button value='Open' className='btn' handleClick={handleOpenClick} />
      <Button value='Upload' className='btn primary' disabled={uploadDisabled} />
      <PreviewContainer>{previewElements}</PreviewContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Here is vanilla JS code I want to rewrite using ReactJS:

```
function upload(selector, { multiple = false, accept = [], onUpload = function () {} } = {}) {
  const inputEl = document.querySelector(selector);
  let files = [];

  if (multiple) {
    inputEl.setAttribute('multiple', true);
  }

  if (accept.length) {
    inputEl.setAttribute('accept', accept.join(', '));
  }

  const previewEl = document.createElement('div');
  previewEl.classList.add('preview');

  const openBtn = document.createElement('button');
  openBtn.classList.add('btn');
  openBtn.textContent = 'Open';

  const uploadBtn = document.createElement('button');
  uploadBtn.classList.add('btn', 'primary');
  uploadBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  uploadBtn.textContent = 'Upload';

  inputEl.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', previewEl);
  inputEl.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', uploadBtn);
  inputEl.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', openBtn);

  const triggerInput = () => inputEl.click();
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.files) return;

    previewEl.innerHTML = '';

    files = Array.from(event.target.files);

    files.forEach((file) => {
      if (!file.type.match('image')) return;
      uploadBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const src = event.target.result;
        const alt = file.name;

        function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
          if (!+bytes) return '0 Bytes';

          const k = 1024;
          const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
          const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

          const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

          return `${parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm))} ${sizes[i]}`;
        }

        previewEl.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'afterbegin',
          `<div class="preview-image">
             <div class="preview-remove" data-name="${file.name}">&times;</div>
             <img src="${src}" alt="${alt}" />
             <div class="preview-info">
               <span>${file.name}</span>
               <span>${formatBytes(file.size)}</span>
             </div>
           </div>`
        );
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  function clearPreview(el) {
    el.innerHTML = '<div class="preview-info-progress"></div>';
    el.style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function uploadHandler() {
    previewEl.removeEventListener('click', removeHandler);
    previewEl.querySelectorAll('.preview-remove').forEach((el) => el.remove());
    previewEl.querySelectorAll('.preview-info').forEach(clearPreview);
    onUpload(files, previewEl.querySelectorAll('.preview-info-progress'));
  }

  function removeHandler(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest('.preview-remove')) return;
    files = files.filter((file) => file.name != event.target.closest('.preview-remove').dataset.name);
    if (!files.length) uploadBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    event.target.closest('.preview-image').remove();
  }

  previewEl.addEventListener('click', removeHandler);
  openBtn.addEventListener('click', triggerInput);
  inputEl.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', uploadHandler);
}

export default upload;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you mean to add an array of  for example, and pass them as children.
in React there is a built-in props name children. Check out [this source](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Children) for that

In addition, I think you have to change the code in this way for having a better result.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Button from "../Button/Button"
import PreviewContainer from "../PreviewContainer/PreviewContainer"
import Preview from "../Preview/Preview"

function Preview({ children }) {
return <PreviewContainer>{children}</PreviewContainer>
}

function Card({ accept }) {
let [uploadDisabled, setUploadDisabled] = useState(true)
let [multiple, setMultiple] = useState(true)
let [files, setFiles] = useState([])
let previewElements = []

useEffect(() => {
if (files.length) setUploadDisabled(false)

previewElements = files.map((file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const src = event.target.result
    const alt = file.name

    function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
      if (!+bytes) return "0 Bytes"

      const k = 1024
      const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals
      const sizes = [
        "Bytes",
        "KB",
        "MB",
        "GB",
        "TB",
        "PB",
        "EB",
        "ZB",
        "YB",
      ]

      const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k))

      return `${parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm))} ${
        sizes[i]
      }`
    }
    return { src, alt }
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
})
}, [files])

function handleOpenClick() {
const inputEl = document.getElementById("file")
inputEl.click()
}

function handleInputChange(event) {
event.preventDefault()

if (!event.target.files) return

setFiles(Array.from(event.target.files))
}

return (
<div className="card">
  <input
    type="file"
    id="file"
    multiple={multiple}
    onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
    accept={accept.join(",")}
  />
  <Button value="Open" className="btn" handleClick={handleOpenClick} />
  <Button
    value="Upload"
    className="btn primary"
    disabled={uploadDisabled}
  />
  <Preview>
    {
      previewElements.map((prevEl) => (
        <img src={prevEl.src} alt={prevEl.alt} />
      ))
      // here you need to add children
    }
  </Preview>
</div>
)
}

export default Card
```

pay attention that the function formatBytes is not called.